# validity of file descriptors of device files

Tags: c, linux, file-descriptor

I have an app which opens device files of harddisks. `/dev/sda` or something like that. 
Now lets say my app opens the disk and in between any work that is done to the disk, I disconnect the disk and reconnect a different disk which again is the device file `/dev/sda`.

Is the file descripter still valid or does linux know it is a different disk and fail operations on that file descriptor accordingly?

Comment: It probably depends on the kernel. With a modern kernel the new /dev/sda should be deleted and recreated with a different inode, thus not connected to any open file descriptor. Very old kernels used permanent device files, and may just not notice the disconnect/reconnect events, so any operation would go to the new disk.

Comment: all right, I am using only kernels which are compatible with udev which should be fine then :)

Answer (score 0):

A good way to deal with this would be to write a [udev rule](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html) so that a particular hard disk with a particular vendor ID is mounted in a certain way, that way you would be certain that the File descriptor would fail if you unplugged one hard disk and reconnected another.

Comment: I cannot use any of the ID strings since the harddisks that I am using will be random of any vendor. what I could do is use libudev to manually void a fd if a harddisk is disconnected